# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection Error on CRA Universal app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, promise, server-side-rendering

I have universal app made with cra-universal library and when the server doesn't receive an api response the ssr server stops and breaks the page. the error that I am getting is UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled within .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`

below is my ssr server code from cra-universal.

```
// import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createReactAppExpress } from '@cra-express/core';
import { getInitialData } from '@cra-express/router-prefetcher';
import { HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';

// import Cookies from 'cookies';
import { getStoredState, persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist';
// import { CookieStorage, NodeCookiesWrapper } from 'redux-persist-cookie-storage';
import autoMergeLevel1 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel1';
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
// import StyleContext from 'isomorphic-style-loader/StyleContext'
import routes from '../src/routes';
import {store} from '../src/index'
import {ChunkExtractor,ChunkExtractorManager} from '@loadable/server'
const path = require('path');
const React = require('react');
const { Provider } = require('react-redux');
const { StaticRouter } = require('react-router-dom');
const { createStore, applyMiddleware ,compose} = require('redux');

const { default: App } = require('../src/App');
const { default: reducer } = require('../src/redux/reducers');
const clientBuildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../client');
const statsFile=path.resolve(__dirname,'../dist/loadable-stats.json')
let tag = '';
//let store;
let AppClass = App;
let serverData;
let helmetCtx;
// console.log("REDUCERS",reducer)
const app = createReactAppExpress({
  clientBuildPath,
  universalRender: handleUniversalRender,
  async onFinish(req, res, html) {
    const { helmet } = helmetCtx;
    const helmetTitle = helmet.title.toString();
    const helmetMeta = helmet.meta.toString();
    const newHtml = html
      .replace('{{HELMET_TITLE}}', helmetTitle)
      .replace('{{HELMET_META}}', helmetMeta);
    res.send(newHtml);
  },
  onEndReplace(html) {
    const state = store.getState();
  //console.log("----SERVER getState----", store.getState());

    return html.replace(
      '{{SCRIPT}}',
      `${tag}<script>
      window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(state).replace(
        /</g,
        '\\u003c'
      )};
      window.__INITIAL_DATA__ = ${JSON.stringify(serverData).replace(
        /</g,
        '\\u003c'
      )};
    </script>`
    );
  }
});

function handleUniversalRender(req, res) {
  const context = {};
  helmetCtx = {};

  // const cookieJar = new NodeCookiesWrapper(new Cookies(req, res));

  const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: storage,
    // storage: new CookieStorage(cookieJar),
    stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel1,
    // stateReconciler(inboundState, originalState) {
    //     return originalState;
    // }
  };

  let preloadedState;

  getStoredState(persistConfig)
    .then(preloadedState => {
      //console.log("SERVER Preloded State", preloadedState);
    })

  try {
      preloadedState = {
        test: 'presisited Data'
      };
  } catch (e) {
      preloadedState = {};
  }

  const rootReducer = persistCombineReducers(persistConfig, reducer);

 /* store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    preloadedState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  );*/

  // console.log("----SERVER getState----", store.getState());
// console.log("getInitialData",getInitialData)
  return getInitialData(req, res,routes)
    .then(data => {

      const css = new Set();
      const insertCss = (...styles) => styles.forEach(style => css.add(style._getCss()));


      const extractor=new ChunkExtractor({statsFile})
      const scriptTags = extractor.getScriptTags()
      serverData = data;
      // console.log("CSS FILES", scriptTags);
      const app = (
        <HelmetProvider context={helmetCtx}>
          <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
            <Provider store={store}>
            {/* <StyleContext.Provider value={{ insertCss }}> */}
            <ChunkExtractorManager extractor={extractor}>
              <AppClass routes={routes} initialData={data} store={store}/>
            </ChunkExtractorManager>
            {/* </StyleContext.Provider> */}
            </Provider>
          </StaticRouter>
        </HelmetProvider>
      );

      if (context.url) {
        res.redirect(301, context.url);
        return;
      }
    
      return app;
       
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    });
}

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('../src/App', () => {
    const { default: App } = require('../src/App');
    AppClass = App;
    console.log('✅ Server hot reloaded App');
  });
  module.hot.accept('../src/routes', () => {
    console.log('✅ Server hot reloaded routes');
  });
}

export default app;
```

can someone please help me out with this one as I am stuck and have to resolve it at the earliest. Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unhandled exceptions, promise rejections and logging can be handled using [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston). If you only need to handle promise rejections and don't want to use third party tools, this can also be done using existing `process` variable e.g.:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (ex) => {
    console.log('unhandledRejection caught:');
    console.log(ex.message);
});

// This will create an unhandled promise rejectin
const p = Promise.reject(new Error('Failing with this promise..'));
p.then(() => console.log('Done!')); // Note 'Done!' will never get printed
```

Note: You MUST add `process.on(..)` before the problem occurs, since it adds a listener for these unhandled promise rejections. Adding it after the code where this rejections occurs will not catch this unhandled rejection. You should place this somewhere **at the top of your code**, just before all the logic happens e.g.:

```
...
const { default: reducer } = require('../src/redux/reducers');

process.on('unhandledRejection', (ex) => {
    console.log('unhandledRejection caught:');
    console.log(ex.message);
});

let tag = '';
let AppClass = App;
...
```

You can identically capture uncaught exceptions using keyword `'uncaughtException'`.

Comment: sorry can you point out where and how do i use it as i am novice and finding it difficult to rectify this.